# Run awk on every file in a directory, then save the output for each file--with the same filename--to a different directory

Tags: awk

Essentially, what I want to do is non-destructively, run awk on every text file in a directory--and put the result *with the same filename* in a different directory

In other words, I want to use awk to manipulate every file in a directory, with the result being a directory containing the results of running awk in a file with the same filename.

Say I'm in directory foo, with files f1.txt, f2.txt, and f3.txt. I want to run script.awk on each of these files, with the results in bar/f1.txt, bar/f2.txt, and bar/f3.txt

Comment: What have you tried so far? What hasn't worked the way you intend, and what has worked almost-but-not-quite the way you intend?

Comment: If you got an answer to your problem then please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much to it, loop over the files and prefix the output directory name to the filename.

```
outputdir=bar
mkdir -p "$outputdir"
for f in ./*.txt; do
    awk -f script.awk < "$f" > "$outputdir/$f"
done
```

That assumes the input files are in the current directory, and `outputdir` is relative to that. So, if you have `foo/` and `bar/`, on the same level, you need to `cd foo` and set `outputdir=../bar`.

---

If that's not the case, we need to remove the input directory name from `$f`. The prefix-removing expansion `${var#pattern}` works here:

```
outputdir=./bar
inputdir=./foo
mkdir -p "$outputdir"
for f in "$inputdir"/*.txt; do
    awk -f script.awk < "$f" > "$outputdir/${f#"$inputdir"}"
done
```

Or you could use something like `"$outputdir/$(basename -- "$f")"` if you're more familiar with that. (Take care with the quotes if you have non-nice directory names.)

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for "inplace" editing:

```
cp -r foo bar &&
awk -i inplace 'script' bar/*
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, if you control the script you *can* handle this there, e.g.

```
 awk -vout=../bar/ '$2=="cow" {print "moo",$3,$1 > out FILENAME; next} $4!="fox" {print > out FILENAME}' *
```

But this will usually be a hassle and personally I would go with the other answers. As [Ed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/133219/ed-morton) notes, with other than GNU awk you probably need to separate `-v` and parenthesize `>(out FILENAME)` which are fairly minor, and change to `>>` and add `close(out FILENAME)` calls, which I consider an even worse hassle :-(

Comment: You should mention that that would require GNU awk for 3 things: a) no space between `-v` and `out=`, b) no parens around the expression that's creating the output file name, and b) not closing the output files as you go. With a POSIX awk you'll get a syntax error from the `-v`, a syntax error for the output file name, and once you fix those then a "too many open files" error due to not closing the output files once you cross a threshold which can be less than 20 files.